# Difference between return[] and return()

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
 function makeArray(arg1, arg2){  
        return [ this, arg1, arg2 ];  
    }   
    alert(window.makeArray('one', 'two'));
</script>
```

Question:

The output of the above script is: [Object Window], one, two, If I changed return [ this, arg1, arg2 ]; to return ( this, arg1, arg2 ); the output is: two. So what is the difference between return[] and return()?

Comment: @DCoder: Don't be rude. If you're a newbie JavaScript programmer, these things might feel subtle.

Comment: @LukasEder and yet this should be covered by any decent tutorial

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't think I've ever seen a tutorial explain this.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'm coding JavaScript for ages now, and I have never thought about using `(a, b)` as an expression that returns `b` as shown by [Alnitak](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17081762/521799). If there is a "decent tutorial" explaining this, then just create an answer and link to it.

Comment: @LukasEder point taken; however, the comma operator is kinda useful when golfing, or in a `for` head in general: `for(i=0, a=[]; i<10; i++)`

Comment: @JanDvorak the issue here is that the comma operator is well documented, and `return` is well documented, but no one ever wrote up the bad things that happen if you inadvertently try to combine them.  `return (a, b)` _kinda_ looks like exactly a function call with a list of arguments.  Except that it isn't.

Comment: @JanDvorak: *however, the comma operator is kinda useful when golfing [...]*: See? It's actually a very good question making people think! :-)

Comment: @LukasEder I've been using the comma operator way before this question, but never in a return statement. I'll try to keep that option in mind, but I doubt that it's actually useful to ever use it there: `return a,b` =>`a;return b`. It could be useful in a braceless `if`, but then again it's rarely useful to do something before returning.

Comment: @LukasEder also, I love that feeling when I kick out all commas and semicolons from my algorithm.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Well, it's certainly a good obfuscation technique...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`return` does not support returning multiple arguments.  Nor does it require braces for its argument, so when you call:

```
return (this, 'one', 'two');
```

then the braces simply enclose a single *expression*, where the result of that expression is what's returned to the caller.

Inside that expression you've actually used the "comma operator" (twice).

The comma expression `a, b` evaluates both `a` and `b`, but the *result* of the expression is just `b` (i.e. the right hand operand).

In your case you've written `(a, b, c)`, equivalent to `((a, b), c)`, hence still returning the rightmost operand (i.e. `"two"`)

Answer (score 1):

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values) might be useful.

Essentially, if you have `return[]`, really `return []`, your return value is a list of items. In comparison, `return(x)` is just another way to call `return x`.

As mentioned by @Alnitak, in `return(a, 'one', 'two')` you are returning an expression using the comma operator.

Answer (score 1):

This returns an array with three elements. In Javascript, the `[]` is for array notation.

```
return [ this, arg1, arg2 ];
```

Whereas this causes the expression to be evaluated, and the last argument will always be returned (arg2):

```
return ( this, arg1, arg2 );
```

To deomonstrate:

```
console.log( ('a', 'b', 'c') ); // c
console.log( ('a', 'b', false) ); // false
console.log( (true, false, 0) ); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no special construct like `return[]` or `return()`. It's always just `return <some expression>`.

Square brackets is an array literal, thus you get an array as returned value. `()` is just parenthesis and `x, y` is always `y` (lookup comma operator).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript the first operand that gets solved is the round brackets , ie, ()
The comma operator resolves to the last operand, ie, 'two' .

```
return ('one', 'two')
return ('two')
```

hence it returns two