# select arrays out of a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

Having the following object `obj`:

```
{"Point Ref":[15629989,564646414,65494949],
"Effective Date":["2008-03-03","2010-12-14","2004-10-01"],
"Identifier":["EM","EM","SC"],"Status":["FI","SI","XC"]}"
```

I can select the first array with

```
obj["Point Ref"]
```

How can I select more of them? (like obj["Point Ref", "Identifier"]

Comment: Is the idea to get back an array of arrays or one merged array?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @asymptoticFault still array of array....... I've got an object containing, say, 10 arrays and I want only 3 of them...

Comment: @DeepakBiswal do you see any `jQuery` tags??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will iterate through all the first-level arrays in the object:

```
var obj = {"Point Ref":[15629989,564646414,65494949],
           "Effective Date":["2008-03-03","2010-12-14","2004-10-01"],
           "Identifier":["EM","EM","SC"],"Status":["FI","SI","XC"]};

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] instanceof Array) {
        console.log(obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Then depending on what you actually want from this, you can either use a multi-dimensional array or concat them.  For multidimensional you would do:

```
var multi = [];
....
multi.push(obj[key]);
```

For a single dimensional array you would do:

```
var single = [];
....
single = single.concat(obj[key]);
```

Comment: Alright, I can use the first solution and with an `if` condition to check if the `key` is inside the list of keys I want ( like `["Point Ref", "Identifier"]`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to build a new array from several existing ones:

```
var data = obj["Point Ref"].concat(obj["Identifier"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the call to return two values, like say in Matlab, it isnt supported.

Look here for alternate options on returning multiple values: [Return multiple values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values)