# Odd javascript behavior

Tags: javascript, function, return-value

```
function foo() { 
   return 1,2,3; 
}

console.log(foo()); // prints 3
console.log([].push(foo())); // prints 1
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please don't frame questions in terms of "challenges".

Comment: Learn about the comma operator and learn about push

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not odd. You're returning `3`, which is pushed into the Array, so the `.push()` method returns the new length, which is `1`.

When you don't log the `.push()` call, but just the `foo()` call, then you're simply seeing the returned `3`.

To be clear, when you do this:

```
return 1,2,3;
```

you're returning the result of the last comma operator, which is the final expression, which is `3`.

---

If you were hoping to push all the values into the Array, you need to return an Array of values, because JavaScript only allows one return value.

```
function foo(){ return [1,2,3]; }

console.log(foo()); // prints [1,2,3]
console.log([].push.apply([], foo())); // prints 3
```

Because I used `.apply()` to call `.push()`, it passes the members of the returned Array as individual arguments.

Comment: oh. So the length is pushed into the array.

Comment: @Meredith: No, the number `3` is pushed into the Array. But the `.push()` method returns the new length.

Comment: `var x = []; console.log(x.push(foo())); console.log(x);`

Answer (score 3):

[The value of a list of expressions separated by `,` is the value of the last expression.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) Thus,

```
function foo(){ return 1,2,3; }
```

is equivalent to

```
function foo(){ return 3; }
```

As for why `[].push(foo())` returns `3`, just read [some `Array.push()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Returns) and it should be obvious: `push` returns the new length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**
Returning "1,2,3" isn't a proper syntax to return multiple values in javascript.  Your syntax seems to end up passing the last digit "3" as the return value.

```
var test = foo()
typeof test
"number"
```

Refer to this for correct ways to pass multiple pieces of data: [Return multiple values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript/2917186#2917186)

**Question 2**

```
console.log([].push(foo())); // prints 1
```

This is correct, because push returns the length of your new array "1", due to the single number "3" output by your original function.