# Using jquery return two array from a function

Tags: jquery

I am having two array

```
 var values[];
  var labels[];
```

How can i return these two variables and get from outsied the function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript/2917186#2917186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return them in an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

```
function yourFunction() {
  var values = [];
  var labels = [];
  //code that modifies `values` and `labels`
  return { values : values, labels : labels };
}

var a = yourFunction(); //`a.values` is `values` from the function and `a.labels` is `labels` from the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Return an object or array containing these two variables.

```
return [
    values[],
    labels[]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can return one value/object/array at a time. Now you can do it in smarter way. 
Use nested Array here.

Put both array inside another array and return that array

```
var newAr = {};
newArr.push(values)
newArr.push(labels)
return newArr
```

There are many other ways to create jQuery Array. Refer [jQuery Arrays](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/) for that.