# Dual variable assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, tuples

If you have a JavaScript function that returns two values, is it possible to assign those values to two variables in a single statement?

For example, in Python it might look like:

```
(var1, var2) = function()
```

I *have* tried a few things my tres look like this:

```
this.(var1, var2) = function();
```

I also tried something along the lines of:

```
this.var1, this.var2 = function();
```

and

```
this.var1 = this.var2 = function();
```

I also attempted using a single array instead of multiple variables, but it would complicate what I'm trying to accomplish later on because the two variables are used to story x and y coordinates.

Comment: Any ideas? You're supposed to try before asking.

Comment: Have you tried writing a JavaScript function that returns two separate values?

Comment: Does this help var1 = var2 = function()  ?

Comment: JavaScript function can return an array or an object with several properties, but not two separate values.

Comment: Since your question assumes it is possible to write a function which returns two individual values, I'd be very interest to see an example...

Comment: @PM77-1 except that `[a, b] = somefunction()` works in Firefox like `list($a, $b) = somefunction()` in php. Allegedly.

Comment: Whoever voted to close with "unclear what you're asking" - the question is very clear: *is it possible to assign those values to two variables in a single statement?*

Comment: @Popnoodles It does work like that in Firefox, interestingly enough (just tried it). However, Chrome gives (more correctly, IMO) an error: `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. I wouldn't rely on such browser-dependent behavior, particularly when it's probably not correct according to spec.

Comment: @ajp15243 me neither. The best answer would be no.

Comment: @ajp15243: Destructuring assignment is a new feature coming in ECMAScript 6.

Comment: @cookiemonster Fancy, so Firefox is ahead of the game.

Comment: @ajp15243: Mozilla's JavaScript is a superset of ECMAScript. They implement new features and then push for them to be adopted. Though sometimes the semantics change, and sometimes they just don't get added at all. They currently have other features too like Proxies, array comprehensions, and `let` variables.

Comment: @ajp15243 I don't think it's ahead of the game. It just tries to have something of its own. Internet Explorer also does the same thing. When it comes to **non-standard**, our code will become lengthier and I bet no one likes this.

Comment: @KingKing: How will code become longer?

Comment: @KingKing cookie monster indicated as much, with them implementing new features and then pushing them to be standard. Every major browser does that, given the nature of browsers and web development. Edit: Yes, the code-becoming-longer statement confuses me a bit too.

Comment: @cookiemonster you have to support **all** popular browsers, **not just FireFox**.

Comment: @KingKing: Anyone supporting all browsers simply won't use that syntax because it'll throw an error. The ones using Mozilla-only features will more likely be extension developers.

Comment: @cookiemonster that's why the code becomes lengthier. If it's a standard you just need 1 code for all.

Comment: @KingKing: It doesn't become any longer if you don't use it. It's not like someone is going to write their application twice just so that they can use destructuring assignment in the Mozilla browsers.

Comment: @cookiemonster I cannot understand why you don't get this point. You have a code FireFox understands but other browsers **can't**, so what you do? you have to support many the things like `if FireFox then .... else if Internet Explorer then ...` Anyway that's the most different thing (I hate best) between web programming and **desktop** programming.

Comment: @cookiemonster I think King King means his/her point from the perspective of someone who is either dead-set on, or has their hands tied with, using the browser-specific code. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @KingKing: It's so incredibly simple. If you need to support browsers other than Firefox, then you don't use Firefox-only syntax extensions. Your example of `if FireFox then ... else ...` won't work because if you use Firefox syntax extensions, the entire program will fail to parse unless you use `try/catch`.

Comment: @cookiemonster That's the way I do. I've limitedly used something non-standard (even in CSS). So that's why such a private feature is useless unless for those who intend to support only FF.

Comment: @KingKing: CSS is different. The browser flags add extra code. I think vendors are backing away from that practice, though it was useful for getting new features out. Kind of a pain to support. It's a pretty different situation with actual syntax extensions though.

Comment: @cookiemonster Aside: Even `try`/`catch` didn't work in Chrome for me: `function f(){return [1,2]}; try{if (false){ [a,b]=f() }else{ console.log('foo') }}catch{ console.log('fail') }`. Still threw `ReferenceError` I pasted in an above comment.

Comment: @cookiemonster the same here is code becomes lengthier, of course there is the so-called prefix-free but looks like it cannot solve all the cases.

Comment: @ajp15243: Ah yeah, a try/catch wouldn't work for syntax errors. Or wait, it's a ReferenceError like you said. Strange that the error isn't caught

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes you can, but it only works in some browsers as an experimental technology, part of the Harmony (ECMAScript 6) proposal, so it's **not recommended at the time of posting this answer**.

See the [Destructuring assignment docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```
function foo(){
    return ["one", "two", "three"];
}

var [one, two, three] = foo();
```

You can do it in two lines which I appreciate isn't what you want but it works.

```
var foo = foo();
var one = foo[0], two = foo[1], three = foo[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question implies there is a way to do this, which is not true at least not at this time. As PM 77-1 said, a JavaScript function can return an array or an object with several properties, but not two separate values.

Here's an example of both:

```js
var one, two;

// Return two values using an array
function foo(a, b) {
 return [a, b];
}

// Return two values using a plain object 
function bar(a, b) {
 return { one: a, two: b };
}

// Assign by index
var testOne = foo(1, 2);
one = testOne[0], two = testOne[1];

// Assign by properties
var testTwo = bar(1, 2);
one = testTwo.one, two = testTwo.two;
```

I would also like to add this is a duplicate question, please see: [Return multiple values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2917175/1883647)

Comment: Given that the linked question at the bottom of your answer is already itself a duplicate of another, I'd link [the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2917175/1883647) instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could return an array and then access them through the array

```
var returnvalues = function(){  

return [value1, value2];  
};
```

Comment: Ok someone down voted me before I could update my answer. I misunderstood the question

Comment: People are ruthless on this site. Let some of us without the reputation at least have a chance. I quickly updated my answer to the correct solution.

Comment: People don't always come back and check their downvotes to see if they should be removed due to updates/corrections, so you may just have to live with it unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Ahhh well :)

Comment: Thanks @ajp15243 if that was you that up voted.

Comment: Well, as the ECMAScript standard stands now, you did correctly answer :)