# How can I return two values?

Tags: javascript, return-value

I have a database column that populates a label. It is date format so it saves entries as yy-mm-dd 00:00.0. I used this code to change it to the format that I wanted when it is listed.

```
var yyyymmdd = value.split(" ")[0].split("-");
return yyyymmdd[1] + "-" + yyyymmdd[2] + "-" + yyyymmdd[0];
```

Now I need to possibly change the color and this is the code I use to do it.

```
if(value.dead){
         $(element).css({"color": "#E33"});
      }else if(value.pairout){
         $(element).css({"color": "#0c9999"});

      }
return value.Date;
```

My question is: how can I combine both of these codes to make them work together to reorder the date and possibly change the color.

Comment: you can return a **Map** instead

Comment: @AlvinMagalona can you give me more details?

Comment: @PM77-1 Value is the value stored in the database.

Comment: if those two are separate functions, say `getDate(value)` and `getColor(value)`, do `var combined = { date: getDate(value), color: getColor(value) };` and returned `combined`.  The color setting might nee d to be refactored so to not assign the color to `$(element)` but just do the detection and return the color code.

Comment: Is `value` in both snippets the same variable?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 5):

A single value is returned via [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) from a function. This value can be any primitive, object or the result from an expression. So, if you wanted to return more than one value you could use either an object or an array.

Answer (score 1):

If those two are separate functions, say `getDate(value)` and `getColor(value)`, do `var combined = { date: getDate(value), color: getColor(value) };` and returned combined. The color setting might need to be refactored so to not assign the color to `$(element)` but just do the detection and return the color code.

Like so:

```js
function getDate(value) {
  var yyyymmdd = value.split(" ")[0].split("-");
  return yyyymmdd[1] + "-" + yyyymmdd[2] + "-" + yyyymmdd[0];
}

function getColor(value) {
  if (value.dead) return '#E33';
  if (value.pairout) return '#0c9999';
  
  return null; //not handled
}

function getCombined(aDate, value) {
  return { date: getDate(aDate), color: getColor(value) };
}

var aDate = '15-01-01 15-02-14';
var foo = { dead : true, pairout: false };

var value = getCombined(aDate, foo);

if (value.color) $('#foo').css({ color : value.color });
$('#date').text(value.date);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='foo'>FOO!</div>
<div id='date'></div>
```