# Indices of Duplicates in Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I am trying to get the indices of duplicates in an array., but can't get my code working for some reason.

I've tried the following

```
var arr = [
        ["OPEL", "12365", "TY"],
        ["FORD", "52874", "QW"],
        ["OPEL", "96542", "TY"],
        ["FIAT", "45621", "TY"], 
        ["FIAT", "74125", "QW"],
        ["FORD", "52874", "QW"]
];

function FindDuplicates(){
    var a = arr.sort();
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++){
        if (a[i+1] == a[i]){
        alert(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You should tag the language

Comment: You have to edit your post and add it to where you added the duplicate tag.

Comment: I see, sorry for that

Comment: I don't use JavaScript, but usually when indexing a multidimensional array you need multiple indices. In your case `arr[index of sublist][index of element in sublist]`

Comment: What are the criteria to compare one element with the other ? Right now you are using the element memory address.

Comment: @Zar thanks that solved the problem!

Comment: No problem, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: As @MaxZoom has stated, your example does not include any duplicates and your first dimension of the array is pointing to a memory address that holds a reference to another array.  Your second dimension would be a value of that array, but what is your definition of a duplicate?  Is it the Make? The Zipcode? Whatever that third field is?  A combination of the three?

Comment: @vol7ron I edited my post. A duplicate is something like this `["FORD", "52874", "QW"]`

Answer (score 0):

When indexing a multidimensional array you need multiple indices. In your case `arr[index of sub-array][index of element in sub-array]`.

Comment: still one thing. It returns only the index of 1 of the 2 indices of the duplicates

Comment: @Ethannn this answer should probably be upvoted, but not selected as an answer

Comment: @Ethannn you can modify your function to return both indices:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

A few things to point out:

- `a` should not be used as a variable name; while it may work, programming convention is to use that variable name for sorting (in some languages, using it in open code this could cause problems)
- `a` and `arr` are pointing to the same array in memory; since you are not copying all the elements (and subelements) of `arr` into `a`, they will both be referencing the same value, so `a` is useless and the sort will be applied to `arr`
- as @Saar has pointed out, since all your elements determine the uniqueness of your array, you can cast the array as a string and compare that value to the string of the next array

See:

```
console.clear();
var arr = [
        ["OPEL", "12365", "TY"],
        ["FORD", "52874", "QW"],
        ["OPEL", "96542", "TY"],
        ["FIAT", "45621", "TY"], 
        ["FIAT", "74125", "QW"],
        ["FORD", "52874", "QW"]
];

function sortAlphabetically(a,b){
  var a_lower = a.toString().toLowerCase(),
      b_lower = b.toString().toLowerCase();

  // sort ascending (a comes first)
  if (a_lower < b_lower)
    return -1;

  // b comes first (move a behind b)
  if (a_lower > b_lower)
    return 1;

  // default: a and b are the same (no sort)
  return 0;
}


function FindDuplicates(){
  arr.sort(sortAlphabetically);

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
    if (arr[i+1]+'' == arr[i]+''){
      console.log('Duplicate at: ', 
                  [
                    '[', i, ']',
                    ' and ',
                    '[', i+1, ']',
                    '\n\tvalue: "',arr[i],'"'
                  ].join(''));
    }
  }
}

FindDuplicates();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Hash object that will store already visited elements. If the new coming element has the same key as previously used then it is a duplicate.

```js
var arr = [
  ["OPEL", "12365", "TY"],
  ["FORD", "52874", "QW"],
  ["OPEL", "96542", "TY"],
  ["FIAT", "45621", "TY"],
  ["FIAT", "74125", "QW"],
  ["FORD", "52874", "QW"]
];

var findDups = function(a) {
  var hash = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var key = a[i].toString();
    if ( hash[key] ) {
      alert("Found duplicate at index " + i + " for " + key);
    }
    else {
      hash[key] = true;
    }
  }
}(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically have an array inside of another array, when trying to compare arrays `==` will not work for you.

In your case since the array is all strings you can do:

```
a[i+1].toString() === a[i].toString()
```

This would work specifically for your case, if you want a more robust code check the answers in this thread on how to check array equality:
[How to check if two arrays are equal with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115982/how-to-check-if-two-arrays-are-equal-with-javascript)

Comment: The solution provided by @Zar seesm to work though. Only thing is that it only returns the 1st matched index

Comment: Another thing. My code creates a new array called `a` and sorts the data from array `arr` in it. 
But for some reason `arr` ends up sorted as well ???

Comment: @Ethannn you are not creating a new array, you are a creating a new variable that references the same array.  You must perform a deep copy if that's what you want to do.  `a` and `arr` are pointing to the same array in memory.  Also, you should not use `a` as a variable name as convention is to use that for sorting variables.

Comment: But if I am creating a new variable, shouldn't the previous variable remain unchanged?

Comment: Why are you voting down if it's working? I didn't say it was a best practice.. I pointed him to correct location.