# Passing two values to a function without calling another function twice

Tags: javascript

I have a function, `rangeInclusive`, which accepts two args:

```
function rangeInclusive(start, end) {
   ...
}
```

In order to calculate the `start` and `end` values I have another function called `getValidYearRange`:

```
getValidYearRange() {
  let validRange = [];
  if (myCondition === 'foo') {
    validRange = [this.calculateValidYear1(), this.calculateValidYear2()];
  } else {
    validRange = [1900, 2017];
   }

   return validRange;
}
```

As you can see I have a condition set that determines whether the range is my hardcoded values, or calls another two functions to get more info.

However I get the following problem, `rangeInclusive` seems to get the arguments as an array and undefined, e.g:

`start = [1900, 2017], end = undefined`
rather than:
`start = 1900, end = 2017`

**I cannot change `rangeInclusive`** at all as it's used throughout the project.

How can I return two values for `start` and `end` without calling functions twice?

Comment: You can't return more than one value. You need to change how you are calling `rangeInclusive`, eg `rangeInclusive(returnVal)` do `rangeInclusive(...returnVal)`

Comment: Can't you just do: `rangeInclusive(validRange[0], validRange[1]) { /* do something */ }` or `rangeInclusive(...validRange) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: I can't see one line where rangeInclusive gets called, that's where you can change something. Please show more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using es6 syntax you could to this by

`const [start, end] = getValidYearRange()`

Now you have the two variables `start` and `end` with which you can call `rangeInclusive`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
[start,end] = getValidYearRange();
```

and refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917483/4798278