# With React, how to declare a variable without needing the wrapping div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I currently have:

```
let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) =>
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <Form.Input {...input} type={type} placeholder={'name@example.com'} />
    {touched && error && <span className="form-control-feedback">{error}</span>}
  </div>
```

How can I update the above to not require to surrounding DIV?, something like:

```
let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) =>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <Form.Input {...input} type={type} placeholder={'name@example.com'} />
    {touched && error && <span className="form-control-feedback">{error}</span>}
```

Comment: How are you using `renderEmailField`?

Comment: I'm using it with redux form, renderEmailField is called:         <Field
          name={email}
          component={renderEmailField}
          label={`Email Address`}
        />

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any version of React before before version 16 you are not able too as each component must return only one element. If you use/upgrade to React 16 you have the ability to do what you are asking in your question i.e. returning an array of dom elements, a string or a number from a component.

```
 render() {
  return [
    <li key="A">First item</li>,
    <li key="B">Second item</li>,
    <li key="C">Third item</li>,
  ];
}
```

See https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings

Answer (score 1):

You could just return an array:

```
let renderEmailField = ({input, label, type, meta: {touched, error, pristine}}) =>
  [
    <label>{label}</label>
    <Form.Input {...input} type={type} placeholder={'name@example.com'} />
    {touched && error && <span className="form-control-feedback">{error}</span>}
  ]
```

But you will still have to return a single component from your `render` method, so for example, if `renderEmailField` is the top-level rendering component, you'd have to still wrap it in a `<div>`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.renderEmailField()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Unless you update to React 16 which supports [rendering arrays of components](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to [Can you return multiple values from a function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript)

The answer is no. You can only return one value, in your case an html element, from your function; hence the surrounding `div` is required.

In React 16, they have added support for returning arrays as stated in the other answers.