# Javascript async/await function - adding multiple returns

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

I have some code that uses Async / Await and works fine...Here is the code:

```
async function main() {
  const x = await myfunction();
  return x;
}
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
async function main2() {
  const x = await myfunction();
  const x2 = await myfunction2();
  return x;
  return x2;
}
```

My issue is that the above code doesn't allow more that one return.

So my question is... Is there a way to have multiple returns working on main2() ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return multiple values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Depending on your use cases, you could also use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return as array or object

```
async function main2() {
  const x = await myfunction();
  const x2 = await myfunction2();
  return [x, x2]
  // or
  return {f1: x, f2: x2}
}

main2()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: Just in case if someone is confused on whether returning an array nor an object - go for an object cause labeling of the values in an object makes it easy to maintain i.e; accessing required data from objects is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
return {
 x,
 x2
}
```

Then access property `main2().x` or `main2().x2`.