# How to add 2nd var in this math based JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, ecmascript-5

We are trying to add a second calculation that meets to the same min, max range of the math in JavaScript.

```
function AllowableRange(Item) {
    ...
    var range1 = // some calculation
    var range2 = // another calculation

    return Math.min(800, Math.max(0, range1));
```

How can I add range2 in the return statement for the same math min - max range?

Comment: What is the expected result in an example , please ?

Comment: when range1 calculation is done it shows that value withing the min and max based on the calculation. 
The second range2 is a different calculation that needs to be in the same math min-max range. So how can 2nd range2 based calculation display the related value as range1 does with above return?

Comment: So both range1 and range2 calculations should show the result based on the same min and max values in the return.

Comment: Please take a look at this [Return multiple values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand the 'show the result ' part.

Well i guess you make first the calculation you made and stock it in a variable

`var min1 = Math.min(800, Math.max(0, range1));`

Then the second

`var min2 = Math.min(800, Math.max(0, range2));`

and then return the expected result

`return Math.min(min1,min2)`

Comment: range1 and range2 are independent of each other. The only point is that they both should show the value between those mins and max. They are completely separate but should from the same function.
I tried something like this but it didn't work. 
return Math.min(800, Math.max(0, range1, range2));