# How to specify a generic assignable type

Tags: typescript

If you need a generic type that can be read as type `T`, you can use `X extends T`. That means when you read the value you can treat it as `T`. E.g.

```js
function foo<X extends number>(x: X) {
  console.log(Math.sqrt(x)); // OK because x can be treated as a number when read.
}
```

How do you do the equivalent for *writing* to a value?

```js
function foo<X extends number>(x: X) {
  x = Math.sqrt(2); // This doesn't work.
}
```

I want this behaviour:

```js
const a: number | undefined = 5;
const b: string | number = "hello";
const c: string | undefined = "goodbye";

foo(a); // Ok
foo(b); // Ok
foo(c); // Error!
```

Comment: Because `Math.sqrt` returns a `number`, but you've said that `X` need only be assignable to `number`.

Comment: The only way `foo(b)` could ever be "Ok" is if `foo` checks at runtime to see if it is a number before using it as one.

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Yes I know *why* it doesn't work. I'm asking *how to make it work*.

Comment: You can't without a type assertion but the example seems contrived so it's hard to suggest anything. I assume you're not doing this merely to reuse `x` instead of creating a new variable.

Comment: You're right - this is for use in [a more complicated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035397/type-safe-field-assignment). I was trying to keep things simple for the question.

Answer (score -1):

Generic type `X extends T` means X has a superset interface of `T`. So X is number's superset. You can't set a subset interface to a superset.

`extends` is not `inherit`

Comment: `X extends T` means "T is a superset of X" or "an X is assignable to T"

Comment: @MingweiSamuel `interface T{a:string}` `interface X extends T{b:string}` X has `a` and `b`, T has `a`. Which is the superset?

Comment: Yes I am aware! The question is not *why that doesn't work* it is *how do I make it work*.