# Return multiple values in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, return-type, typechecking

I want to return multiple values in the return statement of a function in TypeScript. The standard way to do this in JavaScript is to return an array containing the values ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917175/return-multiple-values-in-javascript)), however, as the values I want to return are of different types, I get an error during compilation:

```
function fun() {
    return ['hello', 1];
}

let [a, b] = fun();
console.log(a.substring(1));
```

Error:

```
test.ts:6:15 - error TS2339: Property 'substring' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
  Property 'substring' does not exist on type 'number'.

6 console.log(a.substring(1));
                ~~~~~~~~~
```

How to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify that your return is a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), otherwise it will get interpreted as `Array<string | number>`.

```
function fun(): [string, number] {
    return ['hello', 1];
}
```

We say that the returned value is a specific array where the first element is type `string` and the second is type `number`.  This allows for the correct types to be assigned when [destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#tuple-destructuring).

```
let [a, b] = fun();
console.log(a.substring(1)); // logs "ello" - a has type `string`
console.log(b.toPrecision(3)); // logs "1.00" - b has type `number`
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NBzyzN)

Answer (score 2):

The return type is being inferred as an `(string | number)[]`. To infer as a Tuple you can use const assertions. [TS Documentation for const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

```
function fun() {
  return ['hello', 1] as const;
}

let [a, b] = fun();
console.log(a.substring(1));
```